# Why is the :not selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out why the not selector is not working. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8CKJa/15/

**CSS**:

```css
#full-content, #mobile-content {
    display: none;
}

.collapsed .make #mobile-content {
     display: block;
}
.content:not(.collapsed) .make #full-content {
     display: block;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="content">
     <div class="content collapsed">
         <div id="car">
              <div class="make">
                  <div id="full-content">
                       full content
                  </div>
                  <div id="mobile-content">
                       mobile content
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the full-content div. As you can see `.content:not(.collapsed)` is not suppose to match any of the divs but it is matching the full-content div. How can I hide the full-content div. I am not sure how many `.content` parents there will be. The collapsed class can disappear if the menu is expanded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:not()` selector is working as expected. The issue is that your wrapper div has the class of `content` without `collapsed` and then you have one with the class `collapsed`. Removing the first div makes it work as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/3L7ym/

```
<div class="content collapsed">
     <div id="car">
          <div class="make">
              <div id="full-content">
                   full content
              </div>
              <div id="mobile-content">
                   mobile content
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: There will be parent content classes. And I will not know how many parent content parents there will be. What I am trying to do - is it still possible?

Comment: @Luke101: You'll have an easier time using an overriding rule instead, but if you edit your question to include some examples of this we might be able to determine a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are looking to key off of `.collapsed` and you can't know ahead of time how many `.content` containers you'll have, you may be able to simplify the whole thing by removing the `:not` selector:

```
.collapsed #mobile-content {
     display: block;
}
.collapsed #full-content, #mobile-content {
     display: none;
}
```

**[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8CKJa/18/)**

Comment: You've misunderstood the quote. The argument in the functional notation `:not(.collapsed)` is `.collapsed` - it's only the `:not()` pseudo-class *itself* that does not count, i.e. the specificity is not equal to `:not()` + `.collapsed`, but only `.collapsed`. That said, this is not an issue of specificity at all.

Comment: @BoltClock You are correct - I did misunderstand. The argument itself does count. I'd like to edit my answer but I'm not quite sure I get how much it counts for with regard to selector weight. http://jsfiddle.net/8CKJa/19/

Comment: It seems that the CSS is targeting `#full-content` and `#mobile-content` separately. When comparing specificity, you only compare selectors that match the same element - in this case, `.collapsed .make #mobile-content` is more specific than `#mobile-content` and `.content:not(.collapsed) .make #full-content` is more specific than `#full-content`, but since each pair of selectors matches a different element, as the answers have shown, the issue doesn't lie in specificity but how the selectors are being matched.

Comment: Cheers @BoltClock. I removed all the `:not()` stuff from my answer because I'm still a bit confused. http://jsfiddle.net/8CKJa/22/ doesn't make sense yet but perhaps I'll just ask a question instead of doing it in the comments here. :)